# An exact triangle of (derived) sheaves.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

For a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$, denote by $\mathcal{F}[n]$ ($n\in \mathbb{ Z}$) the complex of sheaves given by
$$\mathcal{F}[n]_i=\begin{cases}
\mathcal{F}&\text{if }i= n\\
0&\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Let $C$ be an object in the category of derived constructible sheaves on $\mathbb{C}$, that I denote by $D_c(\mathbb C)$. It seems there is (maybe under some mild assumptions) an exact triangle
$$H^{-1}(C)[1]\rightarrow C\rightarrow H^0(C)[0]$$
in $D_c(\mathbb C)$, where $H^i(C)$ denotes the sheaf obtained taking the $i^{\text{th}}$-homology  of $C$.

I know little about derived sheaves. For instance I know how we construct the categories $D(X)$ and $D_c(X)$, but I'm not used to manipulate them. Is the above true? What is the map $C\rightarrow H^0(C)[0]$, how do I describe it? Do I have a similar exact triangle for an object $C$ in $D_c(X)$ for an arbitrary topological spaces/scheme $X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a triangle
$$H^{-1}(C)[1]\to C\to H^0(C)[0]\overset{+1}\to$$
it is necessary and sufficient that $C$ is concentrated in (cohomological) degree $-1$ and $0$. Indeed, $C$ is an extension of a complexe concentrated in degree $0$ by a complex concentrated in degree $-1$ so this is clearly necessary. It also sufficient, for in that case, $C$ is quasi-isomorphic to a complex of the form $0\to C^{-1}\overset{f}{\to} C^0\to 0$. In that case, the map $C\to H^0(C)[0]$ is induced by the map of complexes : 
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
C^{-1}@>f>> C^0\\
@.@VVV\\
@.\operatorname{coker} f
\end{CD}
$$
(note that $H^0(C)=\operatorname{coker}f$). And similarly, the map $H^{-1}(C)[1]\to C$ is induced by the map 
$$\begin{CD}
\ker f\\
@VVV\\
C^{-1}@>f>> C^0
\end{CD}
$$
(since $H^{-1}(C)=\ker f$).

This kind of complexes is appears for example as the cone of a morphism of (constructible) sheaves. (In fact, this triangle holds in any derived category, not just the category of sheaves).

Comment: Thank you very much @Roland! This is really helpful. Two little questions before accepting your answer: 1) what is the map "+1" and 2) is there a triangle, or similar kind of characterization for sheaves concentrated in degree -2 -1 and 0?

Comment: The map $+1$ is part of the triangle, I write $\overset{+1}\to$ but sometimes it is written $A\to B\to C\to A[1]$.

Comment: For complexes of sheaves concentrated in degree $[-2,0]$, there is indeed several triangles of interests. You might want to look for the truncation functors. So for a complex $C$, there exists $\tau_{\leq n}C$ which keeps only the homology in degree $\leq n$, $\tau_{\geq n}C$ which keeps only the homology in degree $\geq n$ and a triangle $\tau_{\geq n+1}C\to C\to \tau_{\leq n}C\overset{+1}\to$. The triangle above is the special case $n=0$ with the identification $\tau_{\leq 0}C=H^0(C)[0]$ since there is nothing in degree $<0$ and similarly $\tau_{\geq 1}C=H^{-1}(C)[1]$.

Comment: (Note that I used homological degree, but I don't know if it is what you prefer since you wrote $H^{-1}$...)

Comment: But what is "+1" explicitly? Anyway cool! Thank you a lot, I found a nice reference for the truncated functors (Etale Cohomology Theory, Lei Fu, pg 304), and now I know where to learn. "Truncated functors" is really the magic word I was looking for :)

Comment: Well it depends on what to you mean by explicitly, I am afraid the only answer you can get is rather tautological. For instance, do you know that maps $A\to B[2]$ in the derived category corresponds to equivalence classes of sequence $$0\to B\to X\to Y\to A\to 0$$ ? Well in that case the map $H^0(C)[0]\to H^{-1}(C)[2]$ corresponds to $$0\to\ker f\to C^{-1}\to C^0\to\operatorname{coker}f\to 0$$. Another way to "explicitly" describe the map : obviously there is no map of complexes $H^0(C)[0]\to H^{-1}(C)[2]$ in the category of complexes, but you can always replace the source and/or the target...

Comment: ... by another which is quasi-isomorphic. So for instance, you can replace $H^0(C)[0]$ by $0\to\ker f\to C^{-1}\to C^0\to 0$ (with $C^0$ in degree $0$). Then the map $H^0(C)[0]\to H^{-1}(C)[2]$ in the derived category correspond to the map of complexes $$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD} \ker f@>>> C^{-1}@>f>> C^0\\@VVV\\\ker f\end{CD}$$.